# How to insert new line in the email using linux mail command?

Tags: linux, email, newline

how to insert new line in the email using linux mail command?

```
echo "Hi xxx, would you tell me something?\\n thanks!\\n -xxx" | mail -s "subject" xxx@gmail.com
```

The email shows the literal '\n', not a newline, how do fix it?

Comment: SMTP uses CRLF line endings, not CR alone and not LF alone. In fact, the RFC specifically says you MUST NOT send a lone CR or lone LF. Also, messages should end in two CRLF, not one. Also see [RFC 5321](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321), Section 2.3.8, *Lines*.

Comment: @jww As already discussed elsewhere, `mail` or `mailx` takes care of this for you. You don't need to know or care what SMTP requires in this particular case.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try using `echo -e`

`echo -e "Hello \n World"`

You can type `man echo` from the command line to read more.

Comment: `echo -e` is brittle and poorly portable. You should prefer `printf` instead; it also simplifies this particular use case because you can conveniently split the lines to separate string arguments.

Comment: I've never expected that I'll search for echo's options, but here we are. even echo has options (because of course it does :D)

Answer (score 18):

With `mailx`, if you send the email to an Outlook user, you can add 2 spaces at the beginning of each line.

```
{ echo "Hi xxx, would you tell me something" ; echo "thanks!" ; echo "-xxx" } | sed 's/^/  /g' | mailx -s "subject" xxx@domain.com
```

Comment: Yes Outlook is a pain but this is real life. It worked just fine for me.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer did not work for me when using the mail command, I had to use

```
\r
```

My whole command is

```
mail -s "SUBJECT" -aFrom:"from@sdf.com "to@sdfd.com" <<< $( echo -e "Line1\rLine2")
```

Comment: using \r made the entire email body look like an attachment to Gmail when i tried it.

Answer (score 5):

Tested on MacOS with Bash 3.2

```
bash-3.2$ mail -s "$subject" TestEmail@gmail.com <<< $(printf "%s\r\n%s\n" "This is Line One"  "This is Line Two")
```

This is a screen shot from gmail of the email received

[image]

Comment: While this works, the here string is superfluous if you are using a separate process to produce the string anyway. `printf '%s\n' 'This is line one' 'This is line two' | mail -s "$subject"`

Comment: For a way to fix this specifically for Outlook users on the receiving end, see https://serverfault.com/a/1083188/34013 .

Comment: This is the only working solution for me! It was a very pain to make this working!

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this issue and resolved it by surrounding with quotes the variable I was piping into `mailx`.

I started with a list of processes from ps i.e. `list="$(ps |grep some_process)"`.

Then when I tried to mail that out as follows, the newlines were obliterated:

```
echo $body | mailx -s "${subject}" recipient@someplace.com
```

But, simply wrapping `$body` with quotes preserved the newlines:

```
echo "$body" | mailx -s "${subject}" recipient@someplace.com
```