# mail bash variable on a new line

Tags: linux, bash, outlook, mailx

echo $d produces output below which is separated by new line after each ';'

```
REVOKE ALL ON URI 'hdfs://nameservice/data/ed_bos_reporting_stg' FROM ROLE ed_bos_reporting; 
REVOKE ALL ON URI 'hdfs://nameservice/data/fq' FROM ROLE ed_edw_telephony_rw; 
REVOKE ALL ON URI 'hdfs://nameservice/data/fq' FROM ROLE edw_rw; 
REVOKE ALL ON URI 'hdfs://nameservice/data/standard_register_mail_piece' FROM ROLE standard_register_mail_piece_rw; 
REVOKE ALL ON URI 'hdfs://nameservice/data/tenant/ed_edw/LSFE_CDC/target_files' FROM ROLE edw_rw; 
REVOKE ALL ON URI 'hdfs://nameservice/data/tenant/ed_standard_register_mail_piece_stg' FROM ROLE ed_standard_register_mail_piece_rw;
```

When I pipe $d in the mail command -

```
echo "$d" | mail -s "subject" -r "Name<Name@somewhere.com >" first.last@somewhere.com
```

The results are not separated by a new line.

I have tried:

```
echo -e "$d\n" | mail -s "subject" -r "Name<Name@somewhere.com >"
echo -e "$d" $'\n' | mail -s "subject" -r "Name<Name@somewhere.com >"
```

And few others with no luck. Any suggestions/leads to documentation would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
This does work fine in gmail. However not in Outlook

Comment: Working fine for me, though Outlook squishes out the newlines and I have to tell it to leave my mail alone after I receive it. . . any chance that's your issue?

Comment: @PaulHodges Just realized that is my issue indeed

Comment: Any explanations on downvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Outlook removed extra line breaks from my message. I was able to use awk to fix the problem.

```
echo "$d" | awk '{ print $0"   " }' | mail -s "subject" -r "Name<Name@somewhere.com >" first.last@somewhere.com
```

This reads every single line, and re-prints it with three spaces at the end. Outlook is now happy.
https://blog.dhampir.no/content/outlook-removes-extra-line-breaks-from-plain-text-emails-how-to-stop-it

Comment: Happy to hear that you solved the problem. You can accept your own answer to mark your questions as solved. By the way: `echo "$d" | ...` can be written as `... <<< $d`. You could even replace `awk` with bash's parameter substitution: `mail ... <<< "${x/$'\n'/...$'\n'}"` (replace the `...` with three spaces. Stackoverflow merges multiple spaces in inline code).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have outlook and cannot test my assumptions, but maybe outlook requires the text to use `\r\n` line endings instead of just `\n` line endings.

Try

```
sed $'s/$/\r/' <<< "$d" | mail ...
```

or install dos2unix and use

```
unix2dos <<< "$d" | mail ...
```

to convert the linux `\n` line endings into windows `\r\n` line endings.

Comment: This results in the report being sent as binary attachment.

Comment: @user3508766 Too bad. Anyway, I found some  [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22098987/6770384) that might help you. They include using only `\r` (try `tr '\n' '\r' <<< "$d" | mail ...`) or writing two spaces in front of each new line and using `mailx`.

Answer (score -1):

if you have output that you'd like separated by newlines on a certain character, `tr` is pretty good about that:

```
echo "$d" | \
mail -s "subject" -r "Name<Name@somewhere.com >" first.last@somewhere.com | \
tr ';' $'\n'
```

This will remove the semicolons. I am sure there's a way to do it without removing them but this is the only way I know off the top of my head; HTH

Comment: would appreciate explanation of downvotes so that I can improve.

Comment: Only a guess: `$d` already contains newlines. OP's `mail` seems to neglect them, so you answer is not a solution to the problem.

Comment: ah. I thought OP meant that the final result after `mail` didn't have newlines. thanks.